# Spread Notation in React.js render function and Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I have a react component that is defined using es6 class notation. In the render function I'm trying to pass some state variables into a sub-component using the spread notation:

```
  render() {
    return (
      // <div>{console.log(this.state.data)}</div>
      <Table 
        {...{
          data,
          columns,
          infinite,
          debug: true
        }} 
      />
    );
  }
```

This didn't work: `data is not defined`. Using `this.state.data` and `state.data` doesn't work either (results in `Unexpected keyword 'this'` and `Unexpected token`).

However, uncommenting `<div>{console.log(this.state.data)}</div>` shows that state is in scope. Finally, this works:

```
<Table data={this.state.data} columns={this.state.columns}/>
```

Am I somehow misusing spread notation in this case? I've seen it work in React function components.

Comment: When you specify the object, it lets you skip the value **IF** the name matches a variable. It seems like you don't have `data` anywhere, so it should be `...{ data: this.state.data, //other props here }` or you can do `const { data } = this.state` previous to the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong variables.
`data` is indeed undefined. You're actual data lies in `this.state.data`

```
render() {
    return (
      // <div>{console.log(this.state.data)}</div>
      <Table 
        {...{
          data: this.state.data,
          columns: this.state.columns,
          infinite,
          debug: true
        }} 
      />
    );
  }
```

Could you try this?

Comment: Looks like a JSX-specific usage I wasn't familiar with (and a handy one). Just tried it and it works. Might add destructuring before the `return`: `const {data, columns} = this.state;` (and `infinite`? can't tell from the question) then the OP's version (assuming `infinite` is in scope somewhere) would work.